# iOS 7 Weather app expand/collapse transition

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, transition, ios7

I'm trying to achieve a view transition like the new iOS7 weather app transition, using a collapsing/expanding view.

Does anyone know if a lib already exist for that ?

Thanks

Comment: ios7 under NDA. Please ask questions about iOS 7 in developer.apple .

Comment: all right, thanks for the tip

Comment: Aldo, I've updated my response and added a link to a project that I think does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your edit Aaron :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[User antol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1314127/antol) put some effort into replicating the behavior:

**https://github.com/Antol/APPaginalTableView**

But note that APPaginalTableView doesn't have a separate controller for the expanded pages.

You can see it in action here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1YvxDMr0yA

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Check out this project. It demonstrates how to do the first part of the Weather app's transition using normal View Controllers and the transitioning API.

---

I know this is a little late for a follow up, but I've looked for a library to do this, as well, but haven't found one.

https://github.com/chefnobody/Colors

I was able to do this using the new UIViewController Transitioning API. This example should get you started:

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/

To augment this example to get the pinch/pull table view cell separation animation you would need to identify the table view cell that was selected (or "selected" relative to the pinch gesture"), then in `-animateTransition:` you would animate the cells above and below the selected cell out of view, revealing your details view controller.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to APPaginalTableView if you are looking to use the storyboard more and set subview controllers to the table. I was working on the same problem and this is my "playground" for it. https://github.com/nissaba/customcellTest.git

Comment: Yes I created it under ios8

Comment: great, i'll take a look later :)