# IOS 7 Weather APP Like Transition/Animations

Tags: ios7

I would like to implement IOS Weather APP like transition, ListView, tap on list item it expands to detail view, or pinch to list also expands to detail view.

Slide left and right transitions. Please let me know how can I implement that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I agree that new 'transition' API from Apple lacks of documentation, and code samples : concepts aren't easy to get... If you have Appe dev account, Go and see WWDC 2013 session 218 'custom transitions using View controllers'

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 Weather app expand/collapse transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853194/ios-7-weather-app-expand-collapse-transition)

Comment: If you're still looking for a solution to the first part of the transition try this: https://github.com/chefnobody/Colors

Answer (score 7):

Here is [some post on a blog I found](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/) that explains Apple new Transitioning API on iOS 7, go through it, read it.

---

In short lines, here are the steps

***1 - Set a transition delegate on a controller***

There are 3 types of transitions you might want to customise :

- `UINavigationController` push & pop transitions
- `UItabBarController` tab changed transitions
- any modal presentation with `presentViewController:animated`

Each of these 3 cases offers its own 'transition delegate' protocol :

- `UINavigationControllerDelegate`
- `UITabBarControllerDelegate`
- `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`

When, from somewhere in your code, you use the methods for presentation :

- `pushViewController:animated:` or `popViewControllerAnimated:`
- `setViewControllers:animated:`
- `presentViewController:animated`

Then, these delegates asks for what I call an 'animator' if an animation is required.

What I'm calling an 'animator' is an object conforming to protocol `<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>` (or `<UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>` in case of interactive transition, like gesture driven interactions). This decouples the animation from your `UIViewControllers` (which might already have plenty of code inside)

***2 - Write the 'animator'***

This is the object responsible for animating transition. This can be a viewController, or a completely new NSObject.

In case of a UINavigationController, you could define different animators for push and pop operation.

***3 - add the properties you need for your animation into your animator, and code the animation***

The 'animator' might implement different protocols, depending on which transition you're trying to customise.
In case of non interactive animations, these are the  methods :

- `- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext` : define the duration of animation
- `- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext` this is where the beef goes. See the example code in link above,
- `- (void)animationEnded:(BOOL)transitionCompleted` for any clean-up after your animation was played.

---

In your case, you might want to add some 'origin' and 'target' `UIView` properties in your animator class (as weak properties of course !)

Then, when you detect 'which' view was tapped by user. (in your `UITableVIewDelegate` or `UICollectionViewDelegate` didSelect methods), you tell your animator so that it can animate with THAT specific frame, then call the 'push', 'pop' or 'presentViewController' , depending on your navigation logic.

Comment: From what I can see, Apple doesn't use the new transitioning API in the weather app, they're simply adding the weather view as an off-screen subview of the tapped UITableViewCell, and then animating the height of the same to take up the whole screen.

Comment: You have access to the source, or some de-compiled binary ? Because on the user side, both techniques feel exactly the same. Although, the advantage of the transitioning API is that you can have a specific `UINavigationItem` if you're using a `UINavigationController`

Comment: No, I don't have the source. I have a jailbroken device, however, which makes it easier to inspect view hierarchies at runtime. The advantage of hiding the view in a table view cell is that you get the animations for free, for barely any work at all, whereas moving cells around via your own custom animations doesn't work as well as I'd like. (I've had to implement the same effect, and ending up doing it exactly like the Weather app)

Comment: caughtinflux could you explain in more detail how you did it? what do you mean by "getting the animation for free". Do you add the subview in the moment the user tabs the cell? Do you use UIPageViewController for the horizontal scrolling? Thank you!

Comment: @obiwahn Did you find a solution? I am working on a similar case.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but I put my attempt at reverse engineering the Apple Weather app on github: https://github.com/chefnobody/Colors

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely pull this off with the transitioning api.

Check out this project, I think it will help:

https://github.com/chefnobody/Colors

I was able to do it using this example from Ash Furrow @ Teehan + Lax: http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/ with some modifications:

To augment this example to get the pinch/pull table view cell separation animation you would need to identify the table view cell that was selected (or "selected" relative to the pinch gesture"), then in `-animateTransition:` you animate the actual table view cells above and below the selected cell out of view, revealing your details view controller. Remember, also to animate back to the table view from the details you need to (during the "pop") know which cell would be selected (scrolling it back into view if it's not already in view) then animate the cells surrounding it from off screen, back into view.

As for the swipe interaction between the different cities you would implement a different `InteractionController` that handles the transitions there. Again, you can probably follow Furrow's example and figure out how to pull it off.