# Difference between UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate and UIViewControllerContextTransitioning

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'd like to implement a custom ViewController  transition. 
There are lot of solutions out there. Most of them are based on either `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning` or `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`.

As they do mainly the same,
what are differences between these methodes? 
(And why does Apple gives us two APIs for the same purpose?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you say that they do the same, have you really read the doc ? Obviously, they don't...
They are both somehow related to transitions, ok for this point, but you need both for different reasons!

Basically, `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` enables you to specify which objects are responsible for which transitions - for example, you might use the `transitionDelegate` of a `UIViewController`, to say "if there is a push transition, then `MyPushTransitioner` (or any other object, it could be your ViewController) is responsible for the transition"

When this is done, `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning` - as its name implies - is just a Context object. It's used during transition by your animator object (which implements either `UIViewControllerAnimatorTransitioning` or `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning`).

This context object gives you access to your viewControllers' views, that you can manipulate, animate, ... and you use it to report transition progress (e.g. : you do an animation of frames and opacity, and then tell the transition context to complete...)

**EDIT**

Here is another SO Post where I gave some hints on how these APIs work -> [IOS 7 Weather APP Like Transition/Animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120589/ios-7-weather-app-like-transition-animations/19122580#19122580)

Answer (score 0):

[**https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol**](http://**https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/**)

> An object that implements the UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
>   protocol vends the objects used to manage a fixed-length or
>   interactive transition between view controllers. When you want to
>   present a view controller using a custom modal presentation type, set
>   its modalTransitionStyle property to UIModalPresentationCustom and
>   assign an object that conforms to this protocol to its
>   transitioningDelegate property. When you present that view controller,
>   UIKit queries your transitioning delegate for the objects to use when
>   animating the view controller into position.

**https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerContextTransitioning_protocol/index.html**

> The UIViewControllerContextTransitioning protocol’s methods provide
>   contextual information for transition animations between view
>   controllers. Do not adopt this protocol in your own classes, nor
>   should you directly create objects that adopt this protocol. During a
>   transition, the animator objects involved in that transition receive a
>   fully configured context object from UIKit. Custom animator
>   objects—objects that adopt the UIViewControllerAnimatorTransitioning
>   or UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning protocol—should simply
>   retrieve the information they need from the provided object.