# iOS8 Weather app like scrolling

Tags: ios

I was looking for a way to implement similar behaviour to iOS Weather app UI.

I've tried to add a gesture recognizer on table view and handle table view moving, but it blocks table view native recognizer.

I've tried adding table view to scroll view, but in that case my table view also has problem with touches.

Similar questions on Stackoverflow doesn't help. Any tutorials or suggestions on it?

Comment: Not an ios dev so I can't say for sure, but would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674752/ios8-weather-app-like-scrolling or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853194/ios-7-weather-app-expand-collapse-transition be useful to you?

Comment: @computerfreaker it was iOs7 app. iOS8,9 has different animations